# Javascript Splitting A Astring

Tags: javascript

How do i split into following output:

Desired Output:

**This**
**is**
**my**
**lovely**
**country**

Meaning to say,each time a space is encountered,it will do splitting.
However,through my search...I found most doing the splitting that ended with a comma
such as  <--This,is,my,lovely,country--> as I wanted to get above output where when a space is encountered,it will be splitted into new line without comma.

My current code is

```
    function split(a)
    {
        var x;
        x=a.split(" ");
        document.write(x);
    }
    var A;
    A = window.prompt("Enter string:", "");
    split(A);
```

Comment: `document.write(x.join("\n"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the split() result as an array :

```
   function split(a)
    {
        var x;
    x=a.split(" ");
      //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
        for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            document.write( x[i] + '<br> ');
        }
    }
    var A;
    A = window.prompt("Enter string:", " sdf dasf a");
    split(A);
```

Check out my Fiddle  : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Thks.However,it does not teach how to split a new word which is encountered on each space to a new line.
Kindly refer my desired output above.

TQ

Comment: Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ , you need to process x as an array : http://jsfiddle.net/6VmwJ/

Comment: Yes, I missed that on my first answer. He need to treat the result of split() as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use the `join()` method:

```
x=a.split(" ");
x.join("\n");
```

Or you can use `replace()` like so:

```
a.replace(/\s/g, "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `a.split(" ")` to `a.split(/\s/)`. I have a lot more luck with regex than normal strings when using the split method.

Comment: Hi,thks for replying.

Well,I used your method..However is split every single character. & not my desired output yet ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Your answer:

```
<textarea id="demo"></textarea>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "I love my country";
    var res = str.split(" ").join("\n");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I have tested it,

It work fine

```
function gety()
{
   var names="This is my lovely country";
   var re =" ";
   var a=new Array();
   var nameList = names.split(re);
   for(var i=0;i<nameList.length;i++)
   {
     a.push(nameList[i]);
   }
   var result=a.join("\n");
   alert(result);
}
```